# How to pass an array from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

[image: Screencap of how it should work (sorry for the language)]

So i've been asked to remake some registration forms. The way its supposed to work is, that an interpreter chooses X amount of languages in the first select box. Then based on the selections of languages, the user must specify from which languages they can translate from/to.

I want to store this data in a key/value array, with the key being "LanguageFrom" and Value being another array, of "LanguagesTo". This is how i have solved this:

```
function btnTest() {
            var fromArray = $('.freelancerLanguagesFrom').map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            var toArray = $('.freelancerLanguagesTo').map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            var tempArray = {};
            tempArray[fromArray] = toArray;
}
```

This method is being called with an "onclick" function in the html part. The user should specify which languages he can translate to for each of the chosen languages in the first box,
I am aware that this probably isn't the ideal approach, but im still an inexperienced developer, and i'd love to hear your take on another approach.
Now comes my problem:

1) How do i make it so the array wont overwrite the existing array with each button click, and instead just add to the array?

2) How do i process this array on the server side (php), so that i can store the values in my database?

3) Is it possible to skip the flow where the user has to press the save(gem) button after each language he has chosen?

edit: Question 1 and 3 are now solved, my only problem is accessing the array i made in js, on the php side

Comment: I need a bit of a clarification: your objective is having, for each single source language, a list of destination languages. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then you need to get the single checked id in the "from" box (I assume you can't select multiple), all the checked ids in the "to" box, and put them in your array in a similar way as you're doing; just, declare tempArray outside of btnTest() and don't reset it to {} every time, so it doesn't get overwritten.

I'm writing an answer because it's starting to get overlong.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my first issue. How do i read this array on my php server? This is how i acces my other inputs, but how to do i read the array variable now?



` function getFreelancerMetaData() {
        $metaData = array(
            "phonenumber"           => validateInput($_POST["freelancePhoneNo"]),`

Answer (score 3):

1) tempArray exists only in the scope of the btnTest() function. Declare it outside (in the global scope), initialize it as {} and don't reset it every time you click the button. The way you get the fromArray variable may require some tweaking depending on whether the "from" list can accept a multiple selection or not.

2) [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) may help. Create a php endpoint to receive the request and call it using ajax. You can work on the array using [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Send your data using JSON.stringify(tempArray) and read it using json_decode() in your php script, or simply set the request headers as "application/json" to have it done automatically for you.

3) I personally wouldn't automate this process. Let's say I have 4 languages, Italian, English, French and Chinese.

I have selected a desirable state of languages I can handle:

> Italian -> English, French

But I also know how to translate French in Italian so I click, in the from list, French, and I get

> French -> English

Which is an undesirable state, for me, because I don't know how to do that. Especially if I were to select many languages, I'd get, inbetween 2 states I want to save, an indefinite amount of states I don't want to save.

If you still want to do so, you need to move the even listener from the button to the list(s), with the onchange event.

I'd also suggest you do your event binding trough [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/), if you aren't already.

Hope this helped.

Comment: So i have created this javascript method that gets called when the form is submitted:




`  function ajaxTest() {
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data : { result: JSON.stringify(tempArray)},    
   });
  } `

and this php method to read it:







`    function getFreelancerWrittenLanguages() {
        $wlArray = $_POST['result'];
        $wlArray = json_decode("$wlArray", true);
    } `




yet i dont seem to be getting the array properly. Sorry for my terrible formatting in the comments.

Comment: @lasselyngdal if you var_dump($_POST) what do you get?

Comment: im sorry but im not familiar with this method. Am i not supposed to write  `var_dump($_POST['result'])` ? Anyhow my site wont load when i write this.

Comment: var_dump() is used to print to screen the contents of a variable. It's there for debugging purposes, and may mess up your site's html f you var_dump and render in the same scope, but it shouldn't be an issue if you put the scripts in 2 separate files. If you organized your code right, you should see (in your browser's nav) the content of your payload without any ill effect on your webpage.

Comment: Nevermind, had some other error regarding that - but i wrote the var_dump, and it says "NULL" for me

Comment: You dumped the whole $_POST and it says "null"? That's weird... Are you seeing it in your browser's network tab (among the developer tools)? The value is only present during the AJAX call, so you can't just hit f5 and hope to see it.

Comment: Oh, i dumped the $_POST with the variable 'result'.  Now dumping the entire $_POST gives me information about all the input boxes, checkboxes etc. Would you like to see the entire dump? I dont see any data relevant to the Array that im looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207357/discussion-between-vkfan-and-lasselyngdal).